# Getting Unauthorized from from Azure Web API

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, google-nativeclient

I created a basic project using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 for Web API (nothing custom, bare bone) and deployed it to Azure (Free Account) following the instruction [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet).
Then I created a Console client with the following code.

```
 public static async Task<bool> ReadValues()
    {
        try
        {
            // Authenticate the user and get a token from Azure AD
            //AuthenticationResult authResult = await AuthContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(Resource, ClientId);
            AuthenticationResult authResult = AuthContext.AcquireToken(Resource, ClientId, RedirectUri);

            // Create an HTTP client and add the token to the Authorization header
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                //"Bearer" 
                authResult.AccessTokenType
                , authResult.AccessToken);

            // Call the Web API to get the values
            var requestUri = new Uri(WebApiUri, "api/values");
            Console.WriteLine("Reading values from '{0}'.", requestUri);
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
            Console.WriteLine("HTTP Status Code: '{0}'", httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString());
            //Console.WriteLine("HTTP Header: '{0}'", httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization.ToString());
            if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //
                // Code to do something with the data returned goes here.
                //
                var s = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(httpResponse.ReasonPhrase);
            }
             return (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

It works fine when I run the WEB API locally from the Visual Studio in debug, but when I deploy it to the Azure, it returns Unauthorized.
Few common things that I might get asked:

> 1. I do receive a valid bearer token
> 2. I have created the App registrations in the Azure AD for bot hthe WEB API and the client
> 3. The client and WEB API are using the correct redirect, resource uri
> 4. The account I am using to login is the same as the one used to create the Azure account and it has full privileges in the domain/AD/API

On the API side, this is whole of the startup.auth.cs

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory;
using Owin;
using WebApi;

[assembly: OwinStartup("default", typeof(Startup))]

namespace WebApi
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                         ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                    },
                });
        }
    }
}
```

What else should I check?

> Other references
>
> https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/security-and-compliance/azure-active-directory-part-3-developing-native-client-applications/

Comment: Could you add the code from your API where you register the authentication middleware (I assume you are using OWIN).

Comment: Well, the auth config looks pretty much identical to an API I've made. If the `aud` claim value matches with what you have in config for `ida:Audience`, and `ida:Tenant` matches the tenant domain/id, then could it be the OWIN middleware is not running at all?

Comment: Hi Juaunas, updated the question with additional code. I followed the two links that I have shared so all the code is from the VS code templates and these two links.

Comment: So my question in that case, how do I find out whats wrong?

Comment: At least you could try putting in a piece of middleware before/after/both the authentication middleware, something like: `app.Use((ctx, next) =>{ return next(); });` You can place a breakpoint there and see at least that the pipeline *is* run before hitting the controller.

Comment: Debugging in Azure is too slow, I will try that anyways given that I have no other option. If that is the case, say the breakpoints are not hit, what is the remedy?

Comment: I got this working quite easily, I put the relevant code in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/juunas11/ec35b9953c8ee85fc02e9296641e60f6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135745/discussion-between-diceyus-and-juunas).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help from Juunas who provided me with a working copy, I was able to narrow down the cause. When I attached a debugger to the Azure instance of the Web API I was able to see a exception for Bad Audience. On trying to retrace my steps, I found that while deployment from Visual Studio, I was selection Enterprise Authentication in settings that was causing the web.config to change in way that lead to the problem. Not selecting that option, I was able to access the API through bearer token.